# Cassarandra joinWithCassandraTable behaviour

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark cassandra connector with  joinWithCassandraTable  and 
sc.cassandraTable both but i am getting more records in joinWithCassandraTable

I have one partition with name cust

```
val withPartiton = sc.parallelize(Seq(Tuple1("xxx"))).joinWithCassandraTable(settings.cassandra_keyspace, settings.cassandra_table)
  .collect()length;
```

and with simple way

```
 val smpl = sc.cassandraTable(settings.cassandra_keyspace, settings.cassandra_table)
  .where("cust = ?", "xxx")
  .collect().length;
```

both are giving different length not huge difference but I have Consistency ALL for reading and QUORUM for writing

Comment: How many records is returned for ever of cases? How many records is returned for `SELECT count(*) from TABLE where cust = 'xxx';` in `cqlsh`?

Comment: cqlsh doen not respond so i can't run query there
it is because of tombstone